# Error Compiling CSS Asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, errno

I have been trying to deploy a Rail 3.1.1 app on CentOS 6

This is the error I am getting

```
Error Compiling CSS
Errno::ENOENT: No Such File or Directory - /var/www/vhosts/MySite/MyAPP/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets%t43t34t34t...t34t-r32r-r23.lock

/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:343:in 'rmdir'
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Clean the cache folder and try again. Just empty the tmp/ folder

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There were actually 2 problems. First the permissions were wrong. and secondly like Nerian said, you have to clear your tmp folder.

**To set the correct permissions**

```
chown apache.root yourapp -R
chmod 755 yourapp -R
```

**To clear you tmp folder**

```
rake tmp:pids:clear             
rake tmp:sessions:clear
rake tmp:sockets:clear
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

Comment: Why do I not have to do this on my own computer? Is this the only way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Apache server you simply need to make sure the apache account www-data can make executions in the directory.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data .
service apache2 reload
```