# Rails 3 & heroku assets compiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, heroku

I have an app on heroku. Everything is uploaded just fine. But I get the following error on load:

```
    Error compiling CSS asset
    "\A Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: mixins.
     \A Load path: /app\A (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/details.css.scss)";
```

Same error in Heroku logs.. no further explainations.

If I try to compile it locally with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get the error: 
"\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

I read throug SO, and set the encoding to UTF en environment.rb and application.rb

I spent quite some time figuring it out, but have no anwsers, hope you can help me with an answer. 
Thanks, 
Jakob

Answer (score 2):

Try using `gem sass-rails` instead of just sass.

Comment: Also, if you are using active admin. Try changing 
`@import "active_admin/mixins"; @import "active_admin/base";`to `@import "active_admin/mixins.css";
@import "active_admin/base.css";` in active_admin.css.sass.

Comment: I found the error, it is related to some image files, that I have in my assets. If I remove it works. One of the files is this: 20_03_223640_ledlight.png is there a problem with specific files or file names?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I did a search for you and found some people that were able to fix your same problem. Looks like it has something to do with version compatibility: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/361
Good luck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219061/error-compiling-css-asset
This might help you too. Have you tried clearing your tmp folder?

Comment: Thanks..! - It was one of the images that caused problems, cleaning the image folder works.

Comment: No problem. If you found my answer helpful, please check mark it :]