# form_for throws error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

First of all, I am a experienced programmer in PHP, and I am 'checking out' ruby on rails  this weekend. I have set up a server and I have been following a couple of tutorials past week and now I'm busy making a test application. I want to make a user login system, but when i try to create a form as in the tutorials, it doesn't compile... I don't really know how to get a detailed error, my /log/production.log stays empty...

Error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

The error disappears when i remove the two form lines from this view:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
        <% end %>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def login
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :email_address
    validates_presence_of :password
end
```

I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, also maybe how i can see more detailed errors. I tried to find how to enable errors, but it seems that it should output errors by default to ./log/production.log which it does not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're running the app in production mode? Does it work correctly in development mode?

Comment: You will get a much more detailed error if you run it in development mode!

Comment: run app in development mode, or look into logs to get error description

Comment: Thank you guys, I didn't realise it running fully in production indeed. I changed rails_env to development in the nginx config file and I am see much more error now! I'll post my solution if I found it.

Answer (score 0):

After the comments on my post I switched to development to get a much broader detail about my error. It were multiple errors;

1. I forgot to set resources :users in my routing.rb:

   ```
   Helloworld::Application.routes.draw do
     resources :users
   ```
2. I had to clear my tmp folder

   ```
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219061/error-compiling-css-asset
   ```
3. The permissions on my tmp folder were 755, and should be 777

   ```
   Permission denied - /var/rails_apps/helloworld/tmp/cache/assets/D38
   ```

Thanks for your help everyone